# Best JSON array representation c++

Tags: c++, arrays, json

Before i have this json body:

```
{
    "users": [{
            "userId": "userId1"
        },
        {
            "userId": "userId2"
        }
    ]
}
```

This body is send by my java client (its not matter for this case) and i receive in my c++ server with one list.I iterate the list and get all user id from request body.

List example: `std::list<UserId>* pUsers;`

But now i want to improve and make more easy my body request, so i want an body request like this:

```
{
    "users": {
        "userId": ["userId1", "userId2"]
    }
}
```

Note: I only put two users but it can be many of users. I'm new with c++ so i have some difficulties.  What is the best representation to do this on c++? Its is one list too? Its a vector? Its a array of strings? Someone can help me and show me some examples or explain to me the best solution?

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++. The two JSON snippets tell something completely different. The first says you have a collection of users, which have an ID property. This can be deserialized directly into a collection of `User` objects. The second that you have one `users` object with an array of IDs. I wouldn't want to work with the second snippet (I'd be very angry to be honest). It would force me to create multiple `User` objects by iterating over that `userId` array. Never mind adding another attribute to the `User` object at a later time

Comment: Thanks for te comment. So in terms of perfomance the firts solution is better? I thought of the second option just because it is easier for the api clients. For example, twenty users with the first solution will give a much larger body request than the second option.

Comment: Make sure you have a functioning program first, then look to micro-optimzations like this. API clients will *hate* it if you compromise usability for unconfirmed performance improvements

Comment: As for the body's size - who cares, if you force people to spend 100 times more CPU time into reconstructing usable objects? Besides, HTTP response compression will take care of the response size

Comment: I already have the first solution working at the momment. Now i'm doing some changes in api (add new features for example) and i have the idea to make more easy the body request for users, so i remember to implement the second solution. But first i never use c++ and second i dont know if the solution two have more perfomance than the first solution.

Comment: In your opion the first option is better?